# Dynamic Linq return wrong result

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to search address by linq, I use in 2 ways:

Linq:

```
_db.Address.Where(address => address.FullName.Contains(text));
```

Dynamic Linq:

```
_db.Address.Where("FullName.Contains(@0)", text);
```

When I try:

-> `text` value is string (doesnot contain `space`), the result in 2 querys is the same,

-> `text` value is `number` or `string` with `space` inside, the query 1 return right result, and the second one return `null`

I don't have `Sql Profiler`, so I cannot check the general sql.

How to fix this issus and how to work with `dynamic linq` in right way?

Comment: www.linqpad.net will connect to you db and create a context. Then from there you can see generate queries.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: Please help me make it works with Linq.Dynamic?

Comment: can you provide sample input and output data, and also expected output?

Answer (score 2):

I think  you need to do this way:

```
_db.Address.Where("FullName like @0", text);
```

or you can do like this as well:

```
_db.Address.Where(a => SqlMethods.Like(a.FullName, "%"+text+"%"))
```

See more [Details HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods_members.aspx)

Comment: The first way return me this error: `Expression of type 'Boolean' expected`. I want to search dynamic (not only `FullName` property), so the second way maybe not a good approach.